# node vm runInContext Unexpected token 'if'

Tags: javascript

I've faced a weird error while playing with a VM in node.js

Lemme share a piece of the code, that produces an error:

```
  const vm = require("VM");

  const context = vm.createContext({result: null});

  const someEvalCode = "if(0==0){0}else{0}";

  const script = new vm.Script(`this.result = ${someEvalCode}`);

  try {
    script.runInContext(context);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
  }
```

The output:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'if'
   at new Script (vm.js:100:7)
   at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/ypetri/Desktop/my files/apps/nodejsApps/helpMeBear/server.js:1995:16)
   at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
   at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
   at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
   at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
   at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: That's quite clear `this.result = if(0==0){0}else{0}` is not allowed in JS. What do you want to use it for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you can't assign `if` as statement (`this.result = if(0=0){0} else{0}` is invalid syntax). Maybe try ternary operator instead:

```js
  const someEvalCode = "0==0 ? 0 : 0";

  const script = new vm.Script(`this.result = ${someEvalCode}`);
```

Comment: Yea, that's true, my bad, thx!

Comment: The problem is, that `eval` returns the output 0 in that case

Comment: @NgAtom Well, your `if(0==0){0}else{0}` will always result in `0`. What else would you expect?

Comment: ok, I think there is a misunderstanding, let me clarify it -
```
 const a = eval("if(0==0){0}else{0}") // will return 0, so a has 0 now,
```
in case of `runInContext("if(0==0){0}else{0}"))`  it will throw an error.